# How to open already existing text file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

when there is an error in my program, it creates a log file and shows a pop-up message. The pop-up message has 2 options "Ok", which closes the message and "Show log" which, by clicking the button, should open up the log file that I created. But I do not know what to write in the method on the button click. Thanks

Comment: There is a lot of things with proper logging and log exposure. Generally the only reliable way is to have the programm that prompts "show log?" to itself start the real programm. Have a "launcher" so to speak. Some basic setting of the programm return value can tell the launcher "something went wrong, prompt to show the log". You should never delay the closure of a programm if soemthing went wrong. If you run into a fatal exception you can not prompt - and indeed should not try to prompt.

Comment: Generally a logfile must be opened first and keep opened. My advise is to never do that with any file. "Create, use, Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block. The logfile is the **one** exception. As for the exception classification I use, there is two articles on exception handling I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy way to open a file with the default application is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\myLog.txt");
```